# Single Authentication for Wifi, Bluetooth and NFC

Tags: nfc, bluetooth-pairing, wifi-direct

I would like to use a single authentication for Bluetooth(BLE and classic), wifi and NFC between an android phone and a wearable device.Which means , say i connect a phone and another wearable through BLE , then later the phone should authenticate the device in other two communication platforms as well without asking authentication again. Please point me in the right direction.Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
 !

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit of a nonsense. There is no standard pre-authentication step for NFC. The devices just exchange data when they touch. If the software you're using to control what data are transferred requires some kind of authentication step, that's only within that software, so you'd need to use some feature of the software itself to turn that off (e.g. in the settings for the app). It's not possible to give a more specific answer because you haven't described the software you're using.

Similarly, the question doesn't make much sense for Wi-Fi. Usually, the phone will be connected to some Wi-Fi network, and to communicate with the wearable device, it would need to connect to the same network. But the phone doesn't authenticate the device in this step: the device needs the Wi-Fi key to authenticate itself to the Wi-Fi hotspot. The phone already has this key, but for security reasons it can't be extracted by a normal app. Only a root app, running on a rooted phone, would be able to send the key to the wearable via the existing Bluetooth connection, and the device would need to be expecting this data. That is, the designer of the device must have included this feature. It's not something you can add as an end user.